# New div does not inheirt click attribute

Tags: jquery, click

I have a `div` that has a class `cls1` .

When I click `cls1` div a new div is created having the same class as this one.

But when I click the newly created `cls1` div it doesn't create another div...

The class is correct because the CSS rules are applied.

I am using jQuery. Is there any reason for the newly created div not to trigger the click event when clicked?

**EDIT1:**
I tried creating the new div with append but also by making a new jQuery object.

Comment: Can you show the JavaScript you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this to work, you need to use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to bind the event.  These will bind the event to newly created elements.

If you just used [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), or [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), it bound the elements that existed at that time, and that's it.

Answer (score 4):

The `bind` or `click` methods only bind elements that currently exist.

Instead, you should call `live`, which binds to all elements that match a selector, no matter when they were created.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably doing something like this.

```
$(".className").click(function() { /* do stuff */})
```

That will put the function represented in click on those selectors that are on the page at that point.  You want to use something like [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) which will work on new content added to the page.  Here's an example with live.

```
$(".className").live(function() { /* do stuff*/})
```

Delegate is the newer version of this concept that has some better features like allowing you to bind to specific DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you register the click event on div.

Each new created div must register a click callback to create another div